# How to set height of jquery grid?

Tags: jquery

Be default, jqgrid only shows up 6 rows, I want to make it accomodate 20 rows. How should I set up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It has height parameter you can use.  Its default value is "auto".
Also set scrollOffset:0, if you know that the records would fit in to a single page.

Comment: Could you please provide code sample or more detail? how to set height parameter?   Appreciate it!

Comment: Take a look at the samples at the following.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Go to New in version 3.5 -> Grid View Mode 

It shows how to use height parameter and rownum parameters to show more than default number of rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use **rowNum** to set rows count per page and **height** property to set grid height in pixels.
For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: 'GetOrdersPaged',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Id Order', 'Person Name', 'Person Email', 'Order Date', 'Title', 'Description'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'IdOrder', index: 'IdError', width: 50 },
      { name: 'PersonName', index: 'PersonName', width: 180 },
      { name: 'PersonEmail', index: 'PersonEmail', width: 180, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'OrderDate', index: 'OrderDate', width: 125, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 200, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 125, align: 'left' }
    ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 25,
            rowList: [25, 50, 100],
            sortname: 'idError',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: 'Список заказов',
            height:550
        });
    }); 
</script>
```